# Socket only work on same network

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, network-programming

i have a server-client socket code and it's work's fine when the server and client are opened on the same network but if i try to run them on different networks they just dont recognize each other.
what might be the issue?

server:

```
        public static TcpListener listen;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Server";
         listen = new TcpListener(8080);
        listen.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Wait For Connect");
        Socket s = listen.AcceptSocket();
        Console.WriteLine("Client Has Been Connected");
        read r = new read(s);
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(r.Reading));
        t.Start();
        NetworkStream st = new NetworkStream(s);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(st);
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        string massege;
        while (true)
        {
            massege = "server" + ":" + Console.ReadLine();
            sw.WriteLine(massege);
        }

    }
    class read
    {
        private StreamReader sr;
        public read(Socket s)
        {
            Stream a = new NetworkStream(s);
            this.sr = new StreamReader(a);
        }
        public void Reading()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client Has Disconnected");
                  //  Console.ReadKey();
                    Socket s = listen.AcceptSocket();
                    Console.WriteLine("Client Has Been Connected");

                }

            }


        }
    }
}
```

client:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Client";

        bool connect = false;
        while (!connect)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient t = new TcpClient();
                t.Connect("192.168.43.36", 8080);
                Console.WriteLine("Connect!");
                connect = true;
                NetworkStream ns = t.GetStream();
                read r = new read(t);
                Thread tr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(r.startread));
                tr.Start();
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
                sw.AutoFlush = true;
                string massege;
                while (true)
                {
                    massege = "client" + ":" + Console.ReadLine();
                    sw.WriteLine(massege);
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Faild!");
                connect = false;
            }
        }
    }


    class read
    {
        StreamReader sr;
        public read(TcpClient t)
        {
            Stream s = t.GetStream();
            this.sr = new StreamReader(s);
        }
        public void startread()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    string s = sr.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Server Error");
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: the most obvious thing is a firewall.

Comment: You would have to use wireshark to see what is going on on the wire.

Comment: With a different network you do mean a different subnet right ?

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to really troubleshoot what is happening based on your description. But here is a list of what I would do:

- check if there is a firewall on the client side
- check if there is a firewall on the server side
- check if you don't have a NAT/PAT issue. If your server is on your pc and you are behind a ADSL model, cable modem or home router that has NAT/PAT enabled then it is only normal that this does not work.
- install wireshark on both client and server and see what is on the wire.

If you are in fact behind a NAT/PAT device you can install port forwarding and or put your server pc in the demilitarized zone.

Comment: One of the computers is connected to rhe router so thats the problem?

Comment: yep very likely that it is a NAT/PAT router.

Comment: If this helps you please upvote and or mark as solution.